# Jquery Datatable Plugin Conditionally mDataProp?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have defined that for my Jquery datatable:

```
   "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "cName" },
        { "mDataProp": "sName" },
        { "mDataProp": "url" },
        { "mDataProp": "status" },
        {
            "mDataProp": null,
            "sDefaultContent": ''
        }
    ]
```

However I don't null for my last column. I want a conditional default content for it. i.e.

```
if status == active
```

I will put an html tag if equals another another html tag..

How can I do that with jquery datatable plugin?

Comment: MDataProp i believe is deprecated for mData, which also can take mRender as a function call to create new html elements from the aaData array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the datables.net wiki [here](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns).

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "mDataProp": "cName" },
    { "mDataProp": "sName" },
    { "mDataProp": "url" },
    { "mDataProp": "status" },
    {
        "mDataProp": "status",
        "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
            if(data === "active") {
                return '<span>' + data + '</span>';
            }
        }
    }
]
```

You can put your logic in the mRender function to return the HTML you desire.